# PIVOT syntax in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

Pulling my hair out with this query. Maybe some of the experts here can see what I'm doing wrong?

I have a TimeSheetTime Table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeSheetTime(
    TimeSheetTimeID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TimeSheetItemID int NOT NULL,
    OffsetToEntryDate tinyint NOT NULL,
    Hours float NOT NULL
)
```

This is populated with some data as follows:

```
INSERT TimeSheetTime (TimeSheetItemID, OffsetToEntryDate, Hours)
SELECT 1,1,7 
UNION SELECT 1,3,1.5
UNION SELECT 1,0,1
UNION SELECT 2,1,0
UNION SELECT 2,4,0
UNION SELECT 2,3,0
UNION SELECT 3,2,0
UNION SELECT 3,4,1
UNION SELECT 3,5,2
UNION SELECT 3,1,2
UNION SELECT 3,2,4
UNION SELECT 4,3,5
UNION SELECT 4,5,16
UNION SELECT 4,2,1
UNION SELECT 5,3,0.5
UNION SELECT 5,4,1
UNION SELECT 5,3,1
UNION SELECT 5,4,4
UNION SELECT 6,5,4
UNION SELECT 6,1,0.5
UNION SELECT 6,2,3.2
UNION SELECT 7,3,0.2
UNION SELECT 7,5,1.5
UNION SELECT 7,1,0.1
UNION SELECT 8,3,0.4
UNION SELECT 8,5,0.5
UNION SELECT 8,1,0.3
UNION SELECT 8,3,1
UNION SELECT 9,5,2
UNION SELECT 9,3,0.5
```

Now I'd like to return a dataset that has TimeSheetItemID  followed by the PIVOT SUM of Hours, arranged in columns of OffsetToEntryDate.
ie : 
TimeSheetItemID | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6

I tried the following

```
SELECT *
FROM TimeSheetTime
pivot 
(
    SUM(Hours)
    FOR OffSetToEntryDate
    IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
) as TST
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM TimeSheetTime
pivot 
(
    SUM(Hours)
    FOR OffSetToEntryDate
    IN ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) as TST
```

The columns you want to use in your PIVOT table have to be put into square brackets `[ ... ]`.

Getting these results:

```
TimeSheetTimeID TimeSheetItemID 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   1   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2   1   NULL    7   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
3   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    1.5 NULL    NULL    NULL
4   2   NULL    0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    0   NULL    NULL    NULL
6   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0   NULL    NULL
7   3   NULL    2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
8   3   NULL    NULL    0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9   3   NULL    NULL    4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
10  3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL
11  3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL
12  4   NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
13  4   NULL    NULL    NULL    5   NULL    NULL    NULL
14  4   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    16  NULL
15  5   NULL    NULL    NULL    0.5 NULL    NULL    NULL
16  5   NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL
17  5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL
18  5   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   NULL    NULL
19  6   NULL    0.5 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
20  6   NULL    NULL    3.2 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
21  6   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   NULL
22  7   NULL    0.1 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
23  7   NULL    NULL    NULL    0.2 NULL    NULL    NULL
24  7   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1.5 NULL
25  8   NULL    0.3 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
26  8   NULL    NULL    NULL    0.4 NULL    NULL    NULL
27  8   NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL    NULL
28  8   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.5 NULL
29  9   NULL    NULL    NULL    0.5 NULL    NULL    NULL
30  9   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   NULL
```

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Figured it out. It seems that PIVOT can't be done on a number type field value. The following works well. Now I just have to figure out how to make it work within my application.

```
DECLARE @TimeSheetTime TABLE (
    TimeSheetItemID int NOT NULL,
    OffsetToEntryDate varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    Hours float NOT NULL
)

INSERT @TimeSheetTime (TimeSheetItemID, OffsetToEntryDate, Hours)
SELECT 1,'a1',7 
UNION SELECT 1,'a3',1.5
UNION SELECT 1,'a0',1
UNION SELECT 2,'a1',0
UNION SELECT 2,'a4',0
UNION SELECT 2,'a3',0
UNION SELECT 3,'a2',0
UNION SELECT 3,'a4',1
UNION SELECT 3,'a5',2
UNION SELECT 3,'a1',2
UNION SELECT 3,'a2',4
UNION SELECT 4,'a3',5
UNION SELECT 4,'a5',16
UNION SELECT 4,'a2',1
UNION SELECT 5,'a3',0.5
UNION SELECT 5,'a4',1
UNION SELECT 5,'a3',1
UNION SELECT 5,'a4',4
UNION SELECT 6,'a5',4
UNION SELECT 6,'a1',0.5
UNION SELECT 6,'a2',3.2
UNION SELECT 7,'a3',0.2
UNION SELECT 7,'a5',1.5
UNION SELECT 7,'a1',0.1
UNION SELECT 8,'a3',0.4
UNION SELECT 8,'a5',0.5
UNION SELECT 8,'a1',0.3
UNION SELECT 8,'a3',1
UNION SELECT 9,'a5',2
UNION SELECT 9,'a3',0.5

SELECT * FROM @TimeSheetTime
PIVOT (
    SUM(Hours)
    FOR OffsetToEntryDate
    IN (a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6)
) AS p
```